# ssh from screen leads to unknown terminal error

Tags: ssh, terminal, gnu-screen, terminal-multiplexer

I'm trying to make an ssh connection (via lsh) from one Ubuntu host to another from within screen. If I try to run `mc` right after that I get the following error:

```
Unknown terminal: screen-256color-s
Check the TERM environment variable.
Also make sure that the terminal is defined in the terminfo database.
Alternatively, set the TERMCAP environment variable to the desired
termcap entry.
```

The question is - who's causing this failure? Is it local host? remote? some package missing (which?), something not done by `lsh-server`? or client?

Just to be clear - I don't want workarounds like "TERM=xterm mc", I want to be able to use visual themes which support 256 colors on the (remote) console.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally, I've managed to figure out "obvious" package which supply screen-256-color-s (got to be installed on remote machine):

```
sudo apt install ncurses-term
```

fixed the problem for me: nice 256 colors and no need for ugly workarounds with environment variables. Hooray! :)

Comment: didn't work for me on an old ubuntu 12.04. ncurses-term installed fine but I still get 'screen.xterm-256color': unknown terminal type.

Answer (score 9):

Just set another TERM, For example

```
TERM="rxvt"
```

or

```
TERM="xterm"
```

or

```
TERM="vt102"
```

Maybe an `export TERM` helps too.

The `TERM` variable is used by `curses` and `termcap` programs, such as `mc` or `dialog`, to read the terminal escape codes from the terminfo/termcap databases, where the command is executed, so in your case in the remote system.

To support the "screen-256color-s" TERM type this terminal type must be installed in the database.

As a good starting point read `man 5 terminfo`.

Comment: Faking `TERM` will give you many problems, like certain keys not working. It is a dirty hack that, today, should never be done. The correct answer is to install the terminfo for the terminal emulator in question (here, `screen`). Note that you don't need administrative access to do so, as you can use `~/.terminfo`.

Answer (score 5):

GNU `screen` is setting `$TERM` locally, and `ssh` is passing that value to the remote side.  There are a few things you can do.

- Detect the `screen-256-color-s` on the remote side and set to a more sane. From that you can have `case $TERM in screen-256*) TERM=screen;; esac`.
- From the local side, have `screen` set the terminal. In your `~/.screenrc` file have: `term screen`.
- If you have a `screen` command to open the `ssh` call, then add a `-T` option: `screen -T screen ssh user@host`
- In you local `~/.bashrc`, set the terminal if it detects the incompatible one similar to the remote side one above.